# Can't get sentinel value to read multiple cin inputs?

Tags: c++

This program should take in data from another file. This file has numbers like:

2017 3 12

4223

161 10.0 0 2 T

99 5.00 10 3 T

0

581

123 45.00 10 3 T

921 5.25 0 1 N

83 14.99 25 2 T

0

4223 and 581 are the receiptnum; 161, 99, 123, etc, are the item IDs; there are four other inputs after item ID which I will try to deal with later; 0 is sentinel.

What I tried is using a while loop to read the data, and if it's not the sentinel, to process and output item id at the least. Yet it doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double operation;
  int year; 
  int month;
  int day; 
  int receiptnum
  int itemid;
  double regprice; 
  int percentoff;  
  int numpurchased;
  char taxstatus; 

  cin >> year >> month >> day;
  cout << "Date of purchases: "  << month << "/" << day << "/" << year     << endl

  cin >> receiptnum >> itemid >> regprice >> percentoff >> numpurchased >> taxstatus;
  while(receiptnum !=0 && itemid !=0 && regprice !=0 && percentoff !=0 && numpurchased !=0 && taxstatus !=0)
  {

    cout<< itemid << endl;
  }


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please tell what is the problem after compiling?

Comment: Blank output happens. It compiles, but running it produces the "Date of purchases" line and nothing else.

Comment: This will not even get compiled what u put here.

Comment: It does compiles, though.

Comment: Look closely u r missing `;`  after `int receiptnum` and another after `cout << "Date of purchases: "  << month << "/" << day << "/" << year     << endl`

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 loops: one that reads to the end of the file, and one that reads individual items:

```
while (cin >> receiptnum) {
    // Read all item lines
    do {
        itemid = 0;
        if (cin >> itemid && itemid) {
            if (cin >> regprice >> percentoff >> numpurchased >> taxstatus) {
                // Do something with the data
            }
        }
    } while (itemid);
}
```